# Web audio API filter is not working

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

So I'm creating a synthesizer in the browser and want to add few filters to it. I created all the filter stuff and connect my oscillator to the filter and the fiter to audio destination. Now when I choose lowpass filter to play, I get this error in the console and no effects are being added:

```
The provided value '3' is not a valid enum value of type BiquadFilterType.
```

Snippet of my code:

```
function init() {
  octaveNumber = document.getElementById("octaveNum");
  audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);
  osc = audioCtx.createOscillator();
  volume = audioCtx.createGain();
  filter = audioCtx.createBiquadFilter();
  osc.connect(filter);
  volume.connect(audioCtx.destination);
  booleanVal = false;
  osc.frequency.value = freqSlider.value
  osc.start();
  gainDisplay.innerHTML = gainSlider.value;
}

lowpass.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    filter.type = 3;  // In this case it's a lowshelf filter
    filter.frequency.value = 440;
    filter.Q.value = 0;
    filter.gain.value = 0;
})

function start() {
    UI('start');
    volume.gain.value = gainSlider.value;
    filter.connect(volume);
}
```

What is this mean?

Comment: are the allowed filters not these https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BiquadFilterNode/type, so in your case `filter.type = 'lowpass'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you see is pretty self explanatory. Basically, the `filter.type = 3;` isn't a valid BiquadFilterNode type which, as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BiquadFilterNode/type) lists, "is a string (enum) value defining the kind of filtering algorithm the node is implementing."

It's values are the strings: 'highpass', 'bandpass', 'lowshelf', 'highshelf', 'peaking', 'notch' and 'allpass'.

You can find their meanings on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BiquadFilterNode/type) page.

Comment: I was reading some dumb blog post and it was using numbers instead of filter names for some reason. Working now, but get some weird error `The provided value '' is not a valid enum value of type OscillatorType.` on line 104, which is osc.type = this.value; where value stands for waveform value like sine or  triangle. So makes totally no sense.

Comment: @Limpus, Glad to help. Your new error is telling you that your `this.value` is set to an empty string, so it's not what you may think it is (as in, it's not 'sine' or 'triangle' when that line 104 is executed. Perhaps it's set later, or asynchronously). Consider using a debugger, such as the Chrome Browser's DevTools which would allow you to set breakpoints and evaluate your code on-the-fly.

Comment: For the record, the early versions of WebAudio did specify the filter types using numbers.  This was later changed to use a string.  A great improvement, if you ask me.